# What does BigNum::to_dec_str do?

Tags: rust

I need to recreate a Rust function in C#.  This is my C# so far:

```cs
public static string AsSha256Decimal(this string asci)
{
    if (asci.IsDigitsOnly())
        return asci;

    byte[] hashBytes = asci.AsHashSha256();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (byte a in hashBytes)
    {
        builder.Append(a);
    }

    return builder.ToString(); 
}
```

Here's my Rust code:

```
extern crate openssl;

use self::openssl::bn::BigNum;
use self::openssl::sha::sha256;
use utils::error::BIG_NUMBER_ERROR;

fn encode_a_word() {
    let blah = "blah";
    let hash = sha256(blah.as_bytes());
    let bignum = BigNum::from_slice(&hash).unwrap();
    let final1 = bignum.to_dec_str().unwrap();
    trace!("hash {:?} and final {:#?}", hash, final1)
}
```

I can get the correct SHA256 hash but I cannot get the right final value. `hash` looks like an array of numbers, and `final1` is a string but the numbers in the string to do not match one for one.

`hash`:

```
[139, 125, 241, 67, 217, 28, 113, 110, 207, 165, 252, 23, 48, 2, 47, 107, 66, 27, 5, 206, 222, 232, 253, 82, 177, 252, 101, 169, 96, 48, 173, 82]
```

`final1`:

```
63094006986221797353605481996956262747240529547095446989928883355012717129042
```

I don’t understand what the bignum functions are doing; what is the line using `bignum.to_dec_str` doing? It looks like some kind of decimal packing;  is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation for the openssl crate](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.9.11/openssl/bn/struct.BigNum.html#method.to_dec_str):

> `fn to_dec_str(&self) -> Result<OpensslString, ErrorStack>`
>
> Returns a decimal string representation of `self`.

Comment: right.   what does that mean explicitly?  each character in the string is what?  number from the ascii table?

Comment: It's just a string representation of the number represented in decimal. So if you pass in the number 1234, the string it returns is "1234". The documentation I linked has an example that shows this.